# Is it possible to have a customizable Chrome (or Chromium) installation file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I added two extensions to my google chrome that I want to send to some extern users, which are not "technical" people (I mean that they don't have IT skills). Instead of showing them how they can download and add an extension to their google chrome, I want to simplify this task by sending them an installation file of chrome (or chromium) which already contains these two extensions. So, in this case, the only thing that they have to do is just to do a normal installation (with the .exe file since they use only windows) like there are installing a normal google chrome! After that, they will have a chrome which already includes these two extensions.

Can you tall me how can I do that? because I have no idea of it..

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has instruction for doing this here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.  You should be able to do it via a registry addition.

Note, as of Chrome 33, you will need to publish the extension to the store, and you just add update urls.  Chrome does not allow installation otherwise for security reasons.